# Dot-Placing Puzzles

Tags: pencil-and-paper-games

Here are some interesting puzzles that I came up with. If these aren't original and have come from somewhere else, please let me know.

The goal of each puzzle is to place dots on some intersections between two or more lines in such a way that each straight line, somewhere along itself, contains *exactly* two dots. Dots can *only* be placed at intersections. You should also do this in the way that uses the most dots possible. If the rules need to be clarified or if you have any questions, ask in the comment and I'll be happy to edit my answer.

Here is an example of a solved puzzle:

[image]

And here are some for you guys to solve:

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Enjoy!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Nice idea

Comment: So the goal is to find the max amount of dots for the puzzle, but you can't have an isolated dot that won't make a straight line, and you can't have more than 2 in a line?

Comment: (Although I'll just note, I can see at least 4 solutions to the first puzzle just by looking at it)

Comment: @n_palum You don't necessarily need to find the maximum amount of dots. And no, you cannot have one dot on a line. You must have exactly $2$ on each line.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil It's true, the first one has a few different solutions. I believe it has exactly $6$ unique ones. However, I used that one as an example because it was one of the easier ones - the others may not be as obvious. :)

Comment: Hmm.. You may want to clarify that it should be max.. Or have some other restraint that allows unique solutions for every one, otherwise it may come off as very broad. But just my opinion, they look interesting regardless!

Comment: Alright, that's not a bad idea. I'll add that to the directions.

Comment: Oh I didn't mean the example one, i meant the first one as in the first one we had to solve

Comment: Oh, yeah. Some of them are like that. I'll take @n_palum's advice and specify that the solution must use the maximum number of dots.

Comment: @Frpzzd thats a better idea!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [image: Puzzle 1]
>  [image: puzzle 2] 
>  [image: puzzle 3] 
>  [image: Puzzle 4]
>  [image: Lots of puzzles in a row] 
>  [image: And a couple more]

Yeah, here are all the solutions.

The most enjoyable ones were the ones that had asymmetrical answers, like the bottom right one on the first compilation, and the top left on the second compilation. The middle right on the first compilation took a bit of thought to figure out at first, but I didn't like the variations afterward.

These are small, fun, contained puzzles that I feel could be used as a passing fancy, possibly in something like a time wasting puzzle game, but nothing as a massive puzzle. I feel like it'd be nice to see more asymmetrical puzzles, as the fact is that every symmetrical puzzle'll have at least 2 different solutions. It was a fun time waster for a lazy Saturday morning. :)